# Cronjob not running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, cron

I have wrote a small script to check if openvpn is running and start it if it's not.

Here is the script i'm running

```
#!/bin/bash **-x**

ps auxw | grep openvpn | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    /etc/init.d/openvpn start > /dev/null
    log="/root/ServerRestart.log"
    echo "The Openvpn Server was restarted at\n" > $log
    date  >> $log
fi
```

here is the crontab:

```
* * * * * /root/vpnmonitor.sh
```

it shows in the syslog that it runs the script but it does not seem to actually execute, the script works fine when run from a terminal.

Comment: You may find useful to go through the "debugging crontab" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info Many issues are quite described there.

Comment: What does `**-x**` mean in your shebang?

Comment: It apparently makes errors more verbose

Comment: Few suggestion: for number comparison should not you use -ne (eg. [ $? -ne 0 ] ) instead of != . Also make sure you have execute permission on the script. At least keep some time interval between 2 execution of the script..I see all *

Comment: @Cai That's `-x` instead of `**-x**`.

Comment: I have followed everything in the debugging crontab section and it still does not run

Comment: How do you define "it does not seem to actually execute"? If you say `log="/tmp/ServerRestart.log"`, that is, set the log path to `/tmp`, does it write there?

Comment: I define that as it doesn't start up the server and doesn't log anything peculiar with
    grep CRON /var/log/syslog
    
Dec 17 15:30:01 IS-26942 CRON[31266]: (root) CMD (/root/vpnmonitor.sh >> test2.log)

Comment: Well it is not entering in the `if` condition because the integer comparison has to be done with `-eq`, like @narendra commented. So you need `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` ... and then it is likely to be a problem on paths.

Comment: What's your working directory when cron runs this script? You try to write a log file in the current directory. As alternative, consider `echo whatever | logger`

Comment: the script works fine when I run it in terminal it's just a cron issue

Comment: Check if your cron daemon is running (ps -ef | grep -ni 'cron')

Comment: I did, made no difference i'm afraid

Comment: cron is running, it's leaving logs in the syslog
    CRON /var/log/syslog Dec 17 15:30:01 IS-26942 CRON[31266]: (root) CMD (/root/vpnmonitor.sh >> test2.log

Comment: Check on your OS how grep behaves... You command "grep -v grep" may always return 0 so it will never go inside if condition

Comment: @fedorqui I have updated the script to use the full path for log, still no difference :(, narendra the script already works fine in the terminal it's just not running properly as a cron job

Comment: Try `* * * * * root /root/vpnmonitor.sh`. It's work for me.

Comment: Not sure how you are testing..are you sure openvpn is stopped or you have killed it..to make sure your script via cron starts it again..to verify your script is working...if it's already running then also it will not do anything.

Comment: First off, $? comes from the last grep statement in the pipeline.  So, I do not see why your code is correct.  pgrep exists on a lot of UNIX variants, including ubuntu. Replace the pipeline with `pgrep openvpn`, or you like the pipeline, use the `${PIPESTATUS[*]}` array.  I think your code restarts openvpn everytime it runs.  When ti actually runs - @fedorqui is very likely on the first of several problems.

Comment: @iyonizer I just tried that but it still didn't work did you do anything in particular with permissions or?

Comment: Some hosted solutions require the username before calling the script like @iyonizer mentioned.  Do you have a file in your /etc/ folder named `crontab` ?  If so, what is in it?

Comment: I made a new cronjob in /etc/crontab rather than using crontab -e and it works now, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The openvpn service won't start whitout the rigth path.
Try to include on your "vpnmonitor.sh":

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Like:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

logger "VPN restarted from cron"

/etc/init.d/openvpn restart vpn-servername
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new cronjob in /etc/crontab rather than using `crontab -e` and it works now, thanks everyone.